# Elasticsearch how to retrieve file fields when querying

Tags: elasticsearch

When I index textual content, how do I ensure that source.file fields are also retrieved with the result of a query? Does it need to be provided at index time and how? Or, does Elasticsearch figure it out? It doesn't seem like ES can deduce this info without any input....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "source.file fields". I assume you just mean the document you're indexing.

In general, Elasticsearch stores the source by default, i.e. the document you index. The source is also retrieved when querying (`_source`).

Please take a look at the docs where this is explained pretty well:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html